# PHP: Merge three variables (year, month, day) into one date

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I have three variables:

1.) $year (e.g. "2018"),

2.) $month (e.g. "9" or "12"),

3.) $day (e.g. "5" or "21").

I want to merge them into one single variable ($date) in the format of YYYY-mm-dd, i.e. "2018-09-14".

Note that the month "9" and the day "5" now have "0" in front of them.

What would be the best way to do so?

Thank you!

Comment: The best way to do this would be - to concatenate strings into one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just:

```
$year = 1980;
$month = 9;
$day = 5;

$date = strftime("%F", strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day));
```

But why not just concatenate the strings?

```
$date = $year . "-" . str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-" . str_pad($day, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("d-m-Y",mktime(0, 0, 0, $day, $month, $year));
```

Comment: Notice that the OP asked for a different format from what you are providing in your answer. An explanation on why this is better than simple string concatenation would improve your answer.